# JPQL: sum of number in a column

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, dao, jpql

I am new in JPQL and I have a "complex" query that don't work:

I am trying to get the sum of a column data in my database with this code:

the BunusDao

```
    @Override
public int getTotalBonus(int MatiereId) {
    Query requete = em.createNamedQuery("Seance.getTotalBonus");
    requete.setParameter("x", MatiereId);
    return requete.getFirstResult();
}
```

in Bonus Entity:

```
...
@NamedQuery(name = "Seance.getTotalBonus", query = "select sum(e.BonusNumber) from Bonus e WHERE e.matiere.matiereId = :x")
...
```

in BunusDaoLocal

```
@Local
public interface BunusDaoLocal{

    int getTotalBonus();
}
```

but when I retrieve the number it give me just -1 as result

Comment: and what does all the results from "select e.BonusNumber from Bonus e" add up to?

Comment: @Chris I've just modified the code, But I still have the same result.

Comment: @JBNizet yes but the result should be at least 1 and not -1. Another question, in BonusDao, should I use  `return requete.getFirstResult();` to get an int value that will be the requested sum?

Comment: Forget what I said above. getFirstResult() doesn't do what you think it does. Use getSingleResult() to execute the query and get its unique result.

Comment: I choosed `getSingleResult()` before but , it tell me _Incompatible types: required int ... found java.lang.Objet_ ...

Comment: `Integer result = (Integer) query.getSingleResult();` (it might be a Long and not an Integer). Are you using JPA without knowing what a cast is? If so, learn the basics first. JPA is a complex beast.

Comment: @JBNizet It Finally worked. Thank very Much. This is what I did: `Long result = (Long) requete.getSingleResult();
        return result;` ... About your question, yes you're right. Any advice?

Comment: Thinking in Java is a popular free book. The Java tutorial is also a good read. But it's been a loooong time since I learnt the basics of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging and check that the generated SQL is correct.  If it is, try executing the SQL as a native SQL query, do you get the correct result?

What JPA provider are you using?

Comment: EclipseLink. I solved the problem finally with JB Nizet solution. Thank you.